# Python crontab not working

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron

I am using python-crontab to do a simple task for every hour. First, if I set it as `every hour`, it is executing `every minute`. Second, I am unable to iterating over `user job`, It throws me the error :

```
Sequence can not be divided by zero or max
```

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from crontab import CronTab
import getpass

user = getpass.getuser()
print (user)
my_cron = CronTab(user = user)

flag = True
for job in my_cron:
    print (job)
    if job.comment == 'kkk':
        flag = False
        break

if flag:
    job = my_cron.new(command='/usr/bin/python3 /home/'+user+'/projects/elb_poc/src/xxx.py', comment='kkk')
    job.hour.every(1)
    my_cron.write()
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work like that.
Thinking "crontab way" - "every 1" is just * in crontab file.
You should use rather:

```
job.minute.on(0)
```

Your code means "every 1 hour, any minute" - which is as you said - every 1 minute.

[python-crontab manual](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-crontab)